# how to open a project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i downloaded a zip file of LISTViewTutorial, with all files, but i dont kno how to open it in eclipse, as it just opens the file, not whole project....

and i downloaded it from here

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/list-view-tutorial-for-android/
thanks lot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Or

File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace

Answer (score 4):

- Open eclipse
- go to file->new project
- choose your project type (e.g. android)
- select "create project from existing source

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse , FILE >> NEW >> ANDROID PROJECT. A form will come up , click on start project from existing source , navigate to the required directory and your project will open in Eclipse.