# opening and running Files in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, open-source, eclipse-3.6

can I open and run downloaded file (.zip file) into android eclipse(Helios)? I wanna learn android,I found a source code and downloaded it.
Thanks :)

Comment: You must install on your eclipse android sdk. Do you have it?

Comment: so you are asking how to open and run a downloaded zip file in android eclipse, right?

Comment: @BurnAfterReading Yup! that's my point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways are given bellow

**First:** Unzip your project

Choose "Create project from existing source "
[image: Create a new project icon] from toolbar 
In location: browse your unzip project

**Second:**
File > Import > General> Existing Project into Workspace> Select archive file and set the path of your zipped project

Answer (score 1):

Paste your download project in workspace in your disk and select File > Import > General > Existing project into workspace > Browse it and select your project in workspace > Check whether project is selected > Next > Finish > This will import your project in eclipse

Comment: Kumar thanks, anyway after I select the root folder then browse the file where I locate the file, there's a res, bin, src etc. what folder should I browse?

Comment: @Missy i thing you go inside the project folder.inside the project folder we have all this files (bin,res,src etc) so can't go inside just browse the project folder and import it

Answer (score 0):

If what you've downloaded is an Eclipse project, you can simply import it into Eclipse. Try File->Import->General->Existing projects into Workspace-> then select the root folder of the project and hit Finish. It should work! Good luck in learning Android!

Comment: thanks, anyway after I select the root folder then browse the file where I locate the file, there's a res, bin, src etc. what folder should I browse?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question. Did you import your project successfully?

Answer (score 0):

check [how to open a project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309553/how-to-open-a-project-in-eclipse) in android

> File > Import > Existing Project into
>   Workspace