# How to run Android project from folder with gen and auto-gen files

Tags: android

It is kind of easy Q, but I am stick, I have the file ready with all files like java xml files every things, and I have Eclipse ready too, but HOW TO RUN
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your existing project through the following path:

> File->New->Other->Android Project from Existing Code

Then click on the run button to run your code.

To generating an APK you need to follow this path:

> File->Export->Android->Export Android Application

Enjoy :-)

Comment: there is no RUN btn
it is something like chose the file then press OK, I did but nothing shows on the tool

Comment: @user2176371 RUN button or it's RUN option will be displayed when you open a Project, Also to run your application you can right click on your project and then choose `Run As->Android Application`.

Comment: thx man for interested in helping me, but I am still unable to show my project on "packege explorer bar" to run as you said.

Comment: @user2176371 Where is your problem exactly?

Comment: my instructor upload file to do some updates on it, I download it, but I am not able to run it or even show it up in Eclipse

Comment: @user2176371 As I said above you need to open your project first!

Comment: OK, since the folder that I download comes with a lot files inside like gen and auto gen, which one of them should I open, because when I tried to open the project its drop down other files to open and so on.... so which one should i open, sorry for keep asking

Comment: @user2176371 NP, You need to open the directory which containing these sub-directories: `src-res-bin-gen`.

Comment: thank you so much, for feature you and this likn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975942/opening-and-running-files-in-android-eclipse help me